# Parsing temperature from lm_sensors command

Tags: python, bash, parsing, sensors, temperature

Currently I'm using lm_sensors to get temperature information off of my server. I'd like to run a cron job that runs lm_sensors every five minutes, grabs the temperature data and puts it into a CSV file. However, I'm at a loss at how to parse the lm_sensors output. I'd like to parse it with either Python or bash as they're my most comfortable languages. I'm going to paste the current output of the lm_sensors command as as an example out the data I'm using. If someone could point me in the right direction on how to strip the data, I can figure the rest out from there. Thanks for the help.

Example output:

```
$ sensors
k10temp-pci-00c3
Adapter: PCI adapter
temp1:        +0.0Â°C  (high = +70.0Â°C, crit = +90.0Â°C)


atk0110-acpi-0
Adapter: ACPI interface
Vcore Voltage:       +1.42 V  (min =  +0.85 V, max =  +1.70 V)
+3.3 Voltage:       +3.38 V  (min =  +2.97 V, max =  +3.63 V)
+5 Voltage:         +4.95 V  (min =  +4.50 V, max =  +5.50 V)
+12 Voltage:       +12.48 V  (min = +10.20 V, max = +13.80 V)
CPU FAN Speed:      1510 RPM  (min =  600 RPM)
CHASSIS FAN Speed:  1683 RPM  (min =  600 RPM)
CPU Temperature:     +37.0Â°C  (high = +60.0Â°C, crit = +95.0Â°C)
MB Temperature:      +25.0Â°C  (high = +45.0Â°C, crit = +75.0Â°C)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to use Python, use [`PySensors`](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/PySensors/), but really don't re-invent the wheel. Set up any number of monitoring systems like [cacti](http://cacti.net/), [munin](http://munin-monitoring.org/) and [others](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_network_monitoring_systems) and be done with it.

Comment: Didn't know PySensors existed. This worked perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Run sensors with the -u switch, for raw output.  You'll get is something like this:

```
    Adapter: PCI adapter
power1:
  power1_input: 21.950
  power1_crit: 124.947

f71889a-isa-0480
Adapter: ISA adapter
+3.3V:
  in0_input: 3.264
in1:
  in1_input: 0.968
  in1_max: 2.040
```

As you can see, the actual value returned by your hardware sensors will be labled by a string with the form of `sensor_input`.  From that, it should be fairly easy to get the values you want into your script, like my one-line script to monitor the sensors every second:

```
#!/bin/sh
watch -n 1 "sensors -u | sed -n 's/_input//p'"
```

Answer (score 0):

[`grep`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) to get only the line(s) you want, then [`cut`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/cut) to get the field you need.

Or a simple [`awk`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/awk) script.